# Is it theoretically possible to build a pure-JS bittorrent with chromium's installable-webapp API?

Tags: javascript, chromium, bittorrent, google-nativeclient, crx

I think I heard that they're even allowing limited/sandboxed filesystem access now, so is there any barrier?  Does the bittorrent protocol require raw access to initiating TCP connections that aren't necessarily HTTP?  Is there any mechanism or facility of this in the chromium JS execution environment?  I remember there was a bitfox XPI client or something but I can't find it now and I'm not sure if it used a java applet or something like that.

What about NaCL, would that change things at all?

Comment: TimWolla- what's wrong with saying thanks?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the bittorrent protocol require raw access to initiating TCP connections that aren't necessarily HTTP

Yes. Of course clients could implement a way to deal with HTTP Connect requests, but that would do little good as it's a P2P protocol and thus needs listening sockets too for proper operation. Ontop of that it would also need a UDP socket for DHT support.

I can't comment on NaCl as I do not know which APIs it provides. If it has full-fledged socket support and some way to store files then that would be sufficient for BT.